# readStreams with Cosmos for Mongo is failing

Tags: mongodb, pyspark

I need to get incremental data from mongo via databricks. I am trying to use readStreams for that.
The code i am using is:
# define a streaming query
dataStreamWriter = (spark.readStream
.format("mongodb")
.option("spark.mongodb.connection.uri", "mongodburi")
.option('spark.mongodb.database', 'databasename')
.option('spark.mongodb.collection', 'collectionname')
.schema(readSchema)
.load()
# manipulate your streaming data
.writeStream
.format("console")
.trigger(continuous="1 second")
.outputMode("append")
)

To work with mongo via databricks, i have used the below spark connectors:

1. 2.12:3.0.1

Below is the error i get when i use the above connector.
org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find data source: mongodb. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.

2. 10.0.1:
   Below is the error i get when i use the above connector.
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unspecialised MongoConfig. Use `mongoConfig.toReadConfig()` or `mongoConfig.toWriteConfig()` to specialize

I have tried with the different versions of the connector and tried reinstalling the connectors as well.